# Heroku postgres database not connecting

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm playing around on Heroku and trying to link to a postgres DB. My app is linked directly to the github source code. When I run it locally with the Heroku DB credentials and with npm start it works, but not when it is deployed, I've got this error:

```
{"name":"SequelizeConnectionError","message":"password authentication failed for user \"riunhwzbjuwwgw\"","parent":
{"name":"error","length":103,"severity":"FATAL","code":"28P01","file":"auth.c","line":"285","routine":"auth_failed"},"original":
{"name":"error","length":103,"severity":"FATAL","code":"28P01","file":"auth.c","line":"285","routine":"auth_failed"}}
```

Any ideas at all?

Edit : here's the connection

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.dbName, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
    host: config.db.host,
    dialect: config.db.dialect,
    port:   config.db.port,
    dialectOptions: {
       ssl: true
    },
    logging : false
});
```

and my variables

```
db: {
    dbName: process.env.DBNAME,
    username : process.env.DBUSER,
    password : process.env.DBPASSWORD,
    host : process.env.DBHOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
    port : 5432
}
```

Like I said, it works locally. The password is set like the DBUSER riunhwzbjuwwgw, could it be something those slashes? \"riunhwzbjuwwgw\"

Comment: It states pretty clear - wrong password.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying to connect to the database? That probably involves a call to `new Sequelize(...)`. Something is most likely wrong there.

Comment: @DavidRunger updated

Comment: Look at Your Heroku panel. Probably when You set ENV vars, You add unnecessary char (like space at the beginning or at the end)

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup Empty space at the beginning, thx